# feature selection for bayesian logistic regression model

Tags: r, logistic, bayesian, feature-selection

I'm building a Bayesian logistic regression model using rstanarm R package. 10 of my predictors have specific prior distribution and 10 had default (0,1) normal distribution as prior. The result showed that many of the features had a little contribution, and I wish to obtain an optimal simplified model.

In classical regression, I can build different simplified models and compare their AIC or BIC, is their equivalent statistics for Bayesian regression? Or are there any penalizing methods (like LASSO for logistic regression) to shrink the Bayesian regression model? Thanks in advance for your help.